# Get Static Random Value with two seed

Tags: c#, random

> Edit 2: New explanation since it looks like my question are quite vague. My question are
>   already answered by user [boriaz50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8678309/boriaz50):
>
> 1. I want a random-like function where if i input two set of seed/key it will return a static set of value which be converted into ranged
>      number (ex 1-99) using Pseudorandom number generator (PNRG) algorithm
>      (Answered by user [boriaz50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8678309/boriaz50). See his linear congruential generator
>      code for his example or below for it's modification).
> 2. The reason i don't use System.Random is because i can't set the second seed/key of that function. System.Random seems to use "0" as
>      the second seed/key and everytime i use Next() that key increased by
>      one. This mean if i change the position or amount of line that use
>      Next() function then the whole result will change (Making there's no
>      point remembering the seed on the next program build). Edit 3: Just realize in [boriaz50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8678309/boriaz50) first code call "new Random" everytime, its seed/key keep resetting making it a workaway solution.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> public int RandomGenerator(int seed1, int seed2, int minRange, int maxRange)
> {
>     long temp = seed1;
>     for(int i = 0; i < seed2; i++)
>     {
>         temp = (48271 * temp) % int.MaxValue;
>     }
>     int result = (int)(minRange + temp % maxRange);
>     return result;
> }
> ```

---

How do to get the same number every time assuming i have two seed and i want to get a random value between 1-99.

In c# there is a System.Random function but it use next() which mean i can't guess what number that came out assuming i know both seed. Is there another function in c# that able to accomplish my goal?

```
int gameSeed = 123;

public void GenerateAgeList(){
    GenerateAge(1); //Always return for example 23
    GenerateAge(2); //Always return for example 34
    GenerateAge(1); //Since the popSeed is also one also return 23
    for(int i = 1; i<5 ; i++){
        GenerateAge(i);
    } // Always return for example 23,34,10,...
}

public int GenerateAge(int popSeed){
    return unknownFunction(gameSeed,popSeed,1,99));
}
```

Edit 1: The reason i don't use System.Random Next() is because if i added and/or delete variable that use Next() then the result would change.

```
void GenerateHuman(int seed){
    Random rnd = new Random(seed); //Say the seed are 1
    Human i = new Human();
    i.age = rnd.Next(1,99); //randomly return 36
    i.strength = rnd.Next(1,20); //randomly return 4
}
//Say in few month i added new level var to the code
void GenerateHuman(int seed){
    Random rnd = new Random(seed);
    Human i = new Human();
    i.age = rnd.Next(1,99); //still 36
    i.level = rnd.Next(1,5); //randomly return 1
    i.strength = rnd.Next(1,20); //not 4 but 19
}
//Then say i find the age not necresarry and delete it
void GenerateHuman(int seed){
    Random rnd = new Random(seed);
    Human i = new Human();
    i.level = rnd.Next(1,5); //not 1 but 2
    i.strength = rnd.Next(1,20); //not 19 but 4
}
```

Comment: _"i can't guess what number that came out"_ -- what's the point of a random number you can guess? Why are you using seed values at all? Your question is very unclear as to what you're actually trying to accomplish here

Comment: @PeterDuniho Generating a set of numbers that's statistically random but deterministic is perfectly reasonable. Consider the example of generating a minecraft world. You want the world itself to be statistically random and infinite, and to be able to generate "new" variations, but also be able to regenerate the same world without having to store an "infinite" amount of information.

Comment: The question and intent is also pretty clear IMO, if a bit convoluted.

Comment: @glennsl:  _"Generating a set of numbers that's statistically random but deterministic is perfectly reasonable"_ -- yes, I already understand that. I use seeds for PRNG all the time. The question is directed at the OP, with the goal of understanding why _they_ want this feature, why two seeds are better than one, and how they are expecting to use them.

Comment: I don't use Random Next() because it return different result if i add or remove another code that also use Next() (look at my edit). Since i want my program to always return the same result as long as i input the same seeds i require two set of seed. One could either be randomly generated or manual input and the second one as some sort of key so that the result of the first + second seed is always the same.
For example if the 1st seed is 7, the 2nd seed is 1, and the range is 1-5 it will always return 3. Which can't be archived using System.Random since everytime i use Next() the key change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use your method like a static collection of numbers. You can generate new collection by changing the game seed.

The easiest way to accomplish your goal:

```
public int GenerateAge(int popSeed)
{
    return new Random(gameSeed ^ popSeed).Next(1, 99);
}
```

Since Random class doesn't have method to reset its state, you need to create new object every time you need value. This situation may be unwanted.

The solution may be [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator):

```
public int GenerateAge(int popSeed)
{
    long age = gameSeed;
    for (int i = 0; i < popSeed; ++i)
    {
        age = (48271 * age) % int.MaxValue;
    }
    return (int)(1 + age % 99);
}
```

Comment: The second code is my goal. Is there c# library for it or i have to make it on my own?

Comment: Such algorithms are called random numbers generators. Note, there are not only linear congruential generators. For example, look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister. You can find implementations written in C#. But system generators such a System.Random use similar algorithms.

Comment: To be precise, such algorithms generate pseudorandom numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two seeds, you could combine them together in any number of ways to create one seed. As an example, you could use a `Random` like so:

```
Random r = new Random(gameSeed ^ popSeed);
```

`Next` is deterministic for a given seed, so just calling `r.Next(1, 99)` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Random` has [a constructor that takes a seed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx):

If you have two seeds, just combine them in whichever way you want:

```
var random = new Random(gameSeed ^ popSeed);
var n = random.Next(1, 99); // Will give a deterministic answer
```